# Firebase Cloud Messaging test message is not being received on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on Firebase Cloud Messaging with iOS and would appreciate any help:

###### The problem

I followed [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message) on sending a test notification and it’s not working.

###### What I've tried

I’ve sanity checked everything I can think of on the iOS side and it all looks good. Here’s a list of things I’ve checked so far:

- I had my admin generate a keyID and private key file on the Apple dev site, and I uploaded it to my Firebase app.
- I installed the Firebase SDK on my iOS app and copied the GoogleService-Info.plist file to my Xcode project.
- I registered for silent notifications with `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`.
- I registered for explicit notifications with `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { _, _ in })`.
- I captured the Firebase device token in the Firebase delegate method `messaging(_: didReceiveRegistrationToken:)`.
- I sent a test message to that device token from `console.firebase.google.com/project/<PROJECT_NAME>/notification/compose`.

To confirm that the message is being sent successfully, I sent a manual POST request following this doc.

- I generated an access token for it using [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs).
- I put the device token in the request payload under `{"message": {"token": "..."}}`.
  The request came back with a 200 status code.
- I tried it with a malformed access token and device token and it failed, so the device token captured from iOS must be valid.

So it seems the message is being sent. Furthermore, the device token I captured on iOS is valid when being sent in the POST. So I believe there must be something wrong on the iOS side.

The only explanation I can think of is maybe a mismatch with the app bundle ID or APNs token. I’m not an admin so I can’t check the Apple developer site for the token.

Does anyone have a clue what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that someone had previously set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO` in the Info.plist. I flipped it to `YES` and that got it to work.